# Downloading urls with backslashes with wget or curl from IIS server

Tags: 12.10, wget, microsoft, curl

I was trying for some time to find out why I could not download a url like this:

```
http://domain.com/dir/msrubbish.aspx?urlPath=D:\2014\AC_001\English\AC001_FIN_E_182.PDF
```

The URLs were pointing to a Windows IIS server. I have mimicked the headers exactly as they are in the browser, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to convert the back slashes to forwards slashes:

```
http://domain.com/dir/msrubbish.aspx?urlPath=D:/2014/AC_001/English/AC001_FIN_E_182.PDF
```